# What version Flash player has to be downloaded to play .swf files on Windows mobile 6.5?

Tags: windows-mobile, flash-player

I'm trying to view websites with Flash content in Internet Explorer on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device [HTC touch HD2]. It says it has not got the right Flash player. I tried to install the player but the device is giving me an error. It's saying the installer is not a valid Pocket PC application.

How can the problem be resolved?

Comment: smartphone questions are generally offtopic here.  try asking on [PhoneHow](http://phonehow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Operamobile browser and try again